# jQuery FAQ autosuggest answer below title as per StackOverflow

Tags: jquery, autosuggest, proactive

I want to have a support form use the content of the 'problem title' field as a trigger to add a div below with possible answers just as StackOverflow does when you submit a new question.

To clarify, I do not want the suggested answers to be presented as a 'auto-complete' option, I want them to appear below as a suggested answer.

The markup in the page might be something like:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Your problem in brief">
<div id="PossibleAnswers" class="hidden">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Possible answer 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Possible answer 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Possible answer 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

As the user starts to type the summary of their problem the div below would populate with suggested answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something up and running, here's what I ended up with:

```
var do_live_search = function() {

        var stopwords = new Array("a","about","an","and","are","as","at","be","by","but","can't","from","how","i","in","is","it","of","on","or","that","the","this","to","was","we","what","when","where","which","with","won't");

        var keywords = $("#Trigger").val().split(" ");

        var clean_keywords = new Array();

        $.each(keywords,function(i,val){
            if(($.trim(val) != "")
                && ($.inArray(val,stopwords)==-1)
                && ($.inArray(val,clean_keywords)==-1)
                && (val.length > 3)
                ){
                clean_keywords.push(val);
            }
        });

        if (clean_keywords.length >= 1) {

            var joined_keywords = clean_keywords.join('|');

            $.get("/fetch/_search_support_faqs?q="+joined_keywords+"", function(mydata){

                if (mydata != "") {

                    $.each(mydata, function(i, item) {
                        $('#MatchingFAQs ul').append(
                            $('<li>').append(
                                $('<a>').attr('href','#FAQ_'+mydata[i].entry_id).append(mydata[i].title)
                        )); 
                    });

                    $('#MatchingFAQs').slideDown('slow');
                }

            });

        }
    }
```

This was then triggered using the 'Type Watch' plug-in for jQuery (https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch):

```
var typewatch_options = {
        callback:do_live_search,
        wait:500,
        highlight:true,
        captureLength:3
    }

    // Watch for key up events in the search field
    $("input#Trigger").typeWatch(typewatch_options);
```